# Wordpress Add/Edit Post Redirects to home page

Tags: wordpress

I am getting redirected to home page when creating or editing post in wordpress. When I click on publish button it always redirects to home page and post is not created.

```html
<hr>
  <p>some text.</p>
<hr>

<h2>Heading</h2>

<p>test para 1 - </p>

<p>test para 2 Go to - <strong>Setting</strong> </p>
<p>test para 3 - </p>
```

I am not able to save this post but if I post simple text without html tags it saves properly.

Comment: I think this HTML code doesn't help us at all. You will need to post some actual Wordpress PHP code where this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn off mod_security. 
Add this in .htaccess -  Read Full - http://tutorialsplane.com/wordpress-addedit-post-redirects-to-home-page/

```html
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Or contact your hosting provider to turn it off. In my case i talked to hosting provider to turn it off and it worked for me.

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You should check if any plugin or theme you installed cause to it. Did you upgraded to the latest version of WordPress? What about your themes and plugins? If not, try to do it first. Also try to disable plugins that may cause this probelm or change to a different theme to check if it appear there.

Comment: I disabled the plugin also installed new wordpress in sub domain but i face same problem there..

Comment: I think this issue is due ti firewall which is blocking this content. Sometimes when i go to post the above content it blocks me and i can't access the site. Please help if someone have faced the same issue.